# Fault modelling stuck at fault for combinational circuit

Tags: vlsi, system-verilog, fault, production-testing, verification

A circuit has n inputs and n outputs. It is implemented only using AND, OR and NOT gates. Further, there are no fan-out branches. What is the number of s-a faults that remain after fault collapsing?

s-a means stuck at fault

Answer (score 0):

Given the specified conditions, you can only have single input AND & OR gates so that each input flows to a single output. And assuming you really mean both s-a-0 and s-a-1, so 2*n faults.